# Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm to terminate within O(|E|) iteration regardless of time complexity of finding augmenting path

Tags: algorithm, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

Ford Fulkerson Algorithm will run in O(|E|f) time, where f is the maximum flow; however, is there a way to make it run O(|E|)?

One of the solution to make it run less than O(|E|f) is to choose an augmenting path that allows the largest increase in flow by using stuff related to finding a path by using weighted shortest-path problems and such, but can I guarantee it to run at O(|E|) time?

Basically disregard the time complexity required to find the augmenting path (i.e. whatever the algorithm is, let the complexity be O(1)).

If there is no such way, what's the counter example? If yes, what methods do I need to use?

Comment: Maximum blocking flows increase in length by at least 1 each time they're added to the global flow in this family of algorithms. A simple proof by contradiction shows this. So yes it's always possible get a global maximum flow after combining O(E) blocking flows.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your statements? I can't follow you.

Comment: @Gene The question isn't whether such a sequence of augments exists, but whether we can find it.

Comment: @G.Bach I'm not groking your comment. He said ignore the time required to find maximum augmenting paths and asked how many augmenting paths are needed to find the max flow.  I'm answering that question.  It's |E| because after finding that many max blocking flows, the next available one would contain more than the total number of edges, which is of course impossible.  See for example Dinic's Algorithm.

Comment: @Gene so since Blocking Flow Algorithm will always saturate at least one edge per iteration, all edges will be saturated at or before the E'th iteration; therefore, it's possible to guarantee to stop at iteration O(|E|) for Ford Fulkerson (w/o considering the complexity of Blocking Flow Algorithm) right?

Comment: @LarsChung You're correct except to assert this for the basic Ford Fulkerson algorithm itself because that accepts an arbitrary blocking flow. To get the time bound, you want the shortest, which is Dinic's algorithm.

Comment: @Gene Can I use Dinic's Algorithm to compute Max Flow then use this Max Flow graph to make Ford-Fulkerson to terminate in O(|E|) time?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. By the "flow decomposition lemma", any flow decomposes into flow along at most E paths and cycles. So, in principle, you could compute a maximum flow (which we'll assume takes O(1) time, as per your assumption!), apply flow decomposition (the proof is constructive), and take only the flow along the <= E augmenting paths.

The blocking flow argument above is not quite applicable because a blocking flow is a collection of augmenting paths, not a single augmenting path.

Comment: Could you elaborate the computing flow -> apply flow decomposition?